# Grails' respond method outputs HTML content with charset=ISO-8859-1

Tags: grails

I just noticed that the `respond` method in controllers is returning HTML responses in the ISO-8859-1 charset (which garbles my unicode characters). It uses UTF-8 if I set the format to JSON. The `render` method also uses UTF-8.

I'm using Grails 2.4.4 and the Tomcat plugin v. 7.0.55 in development mode without overriding `web.xml`. Both `grails.converters.encoding` and `grails.views.gsp.encoding` are set to UTF-8. I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` in my template if that influences anything.

I've also tried forcing the charset by using `respond myInstance, [encoding: "UTF-8"]` but it didn't change anything.

Is there something I am not seeing or have I hit a bug?

EDIT: my `config.groovy` contains the following mime type definitions:

```
grails.mime.types = [ // the first one is the default format
    all:           '*/*', // 'all' maps to '*' or the first available format in withFormat
    atom:          'application/atom+xml',
    css:           'text/css',
    csv:           'text/csv',
    form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
    js:            'text/javascript',
    json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
    multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
    rss:           'application/rss+xml',
    text:          'text/plain',
    hal:           ['application/hal+json','application/hal+xml'],
    xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]
```

Comment: Can you share Config.groovy's grails.mime.types  setting?

Comment: http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Configuring-Grails-App-for-UTF8-Character-Encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem this is a Grails bug, I've narrowed down the specific case when it happens: you need to have a `static responseFormats = ['html', ...]` limitation on the controller to trigger it. The fact that Grails' `generate-restful-controller` includes the `responseFormats` block automatically makes developers even more likely to encounter this issue.

I've filed a [bug report](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11830).

EDIT: to keep the `responseFormats` block but still have `UTF-8` responses, it's possible to set the encoding manually, perhaps like this:

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
    response.characterEncoding = 'UTF-8' //workaround for https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11830
}
```

Comment: Bug confirmed on JIRA, slated for resolution in 2.4.5